# Drop a layer in raster stack

Tags: r, raster, terra

I have issue using drop layer/subset function to remove raster layer from raster stack that have min and max `value==0`. Please help me correcting this syntax.

```r
Ls_AOI_3_r_sel_stk_v1 <- dropLayer(Ls_AOI_3_r_sel_stk_crop, (maxValue(Ls_AOI_3_r_sel_stk_crop)==0) & (maxValue(Ls_AOI_3_r_sel_stk_crop)==0))
```

Answer (score 4):

Please find below one possible solution using the `terra` library (which is an improved version of the `raster` library)

**Reprex**

- 1 - Creating a dummy raster `r` of class `SpatRaster`

```r
library(terra)

A <- rast( nrows=10, ncols=10, xmin=0, xmax=10 )
B <- rast( nrows=10, ncols=10, xmin=0, xmax=10 )
C <- rast( nrows=10, ncols=10, xmin=0, xmax=10 )

values(A) <- 1:100
values(B) <- 0:99
values(C) <- rep(0,100)

r <- rast(list(A,B,C))

names(r) <- c("red","green","blue")

# To what looks like 'r'
r
#> class       : SpatRaster 
#> dimensions  : 10, 10, 3  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#> resolution  : 1, 18  (x, y)
#> extent      : 0, 10, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 
#> sources     : memory  
#>               memory  
#>               memory  
#> names       : red, green, blue 
#> min values  :   1,     0,    0 
#> max values  : 100,    99,    0
```

- 2 - Code to select layers where min and max are different from 0

```r
r[[minmax(r)[1,] != 0 & minmax(r)[2,] != 0]]
```

- 3 - Output (only the `"red"` layer has been selected)

```r
#> class       : SpatRaster 
#> dimensions  : 10, 10, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#> resolution  : 1, 18  (x, y)
#> extent      : 0, 10, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 
#> source      : memory 
#> name        : red 
#> min value   :   1 
#> max value   : 100
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: @Mohana, you are welcome. Glad that I could help. If my answer fully meets your needs, please consider marking it as "validated" and/or "upvoted" to make it easier for other SO users to find the right answers. Cheers.